# Calling Asp.net Application object inside a static function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an Application Object.

In Global.asax file i use this:

```
Application["obj"] = "test";
```

How can i call this inside a static function.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use [HttpContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx) property.

```
HttpContext.Current.Application["obj"] = "test";
```